# Making a Discord Bot in Python: Why is my function not working?

Tags: python, function, discord, discord.py

Please take in mind that I'm kinda new to Python and very new to the discord API. I'm trying to make a ChatBot using Python in Discord and I have a command that you have to say to enable the bot to speak to you. The command is called talk. To stop talking to the bot, you would have to enable stoptalk. Sadly, the function I wrote to enable stop talk is not working and I don't know how I can fix it. Please help.

```
import discord
from discord.ext.commands import Bot
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio
import time
Client = discord.Client()
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ":")
on_talk = False
 @client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("You can talk to me now!")
@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def ontalker(message):
    global on_talk
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":TALK"):
        on_talk = True

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def offtalker(message):    
    global ontalk
    if message.content.upper().startswith(":STOPTALK"):
        on_talk = False


@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def stoptalk(ctx):
    print("on_talk is False.")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def talk(ctx):
    @client.event
    # Everything I want to do goes here
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your `offtalker()` function. You wrote:

```
global ontalk
```

However the global you try to modify is `on_talk`, so the variable is only changed to `False` in the function's local scope. Instead write:

```
global on_talk
```

Comment: Wow, I am really dumb. I think I may be blind. I don't see how I was stuck on this for an entire day. But apparently that isn't enough to fix the problem. Any advice?

Comment: @SKIENCE Are you able to make it start talking with `:TALK` successfully? If so, I see no other errors within your current implementation. I would guess that the mistake would lie inside the body of `def talk(ctx)...`, maybe it has a loop that's resetting `on_talk`, or simply disregards `on_talk` after checking its value once. Its hard to say without the code.

Comment: That is the code, and yes the talk function works. I don't understand why it the stoptalk function won't.

Comment: @SKIENCE so there's no extra code in the `talk(ctx)...` function? Then how can you tell if it has stopped /started talking?

Comment: @SKIENCE also consider replacing `print("on_talk is False.")` with `print("on_talk is {}".format(on_talk))`, that way it prints the value of on_talk itself. If there's a logical error somewhere keeping on_talk from staying `False`, you'll see that in your print statement.

Comment: Instead, I deleted the first two client.commands because apparently they didn't matter

Comment: No, it's not :(